# Auto Layout issues

Tags: swift, autolayout, constraints

I am trying to get a layout working where I have 9 squares set 3 x 3 and on all device sizes, they are square.

I have tried endless ideas to make it work but can't seem to get it to stay squares on all devices.

I attached below, a picture showing the results and current constraints on the top left corner square.

Any help would be awesome!

[image]

Comment: You should use stackView

Comment: Use `aspect ratio` constraints with Multiplier(1:1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best approach would be use the `stackView`. The advantage will be you do not have to deal with the much constraints. So select the first rows three view horizontally then click on the `Embed in Stack` button whose axis should be horizontal inside your storyboard. Follow the same for second and third rows. Also inside `stackview` you can mention the spacing you want.

So now you have three `stackView` for all the three rows. After that select all three `stackView` then click on the `Embed in Stack` button and whose axis should be vertical and you can mention the spacing you want.

So advantage of doing that is you do not have to worry about the constraints. Finally you only have to apply the constraint on your main `stackView` which hold all your child `stackView`

Comment: Awesome thanks for the info I’ll check out stack view an follow those steps!

Comment: Sure and its very simple to use

Answer (score 1):

While I totally agree that `UIStackView` is a great option, you can also add `Aspect Ratio` constraints (with a `Multiplier` of 1) to your squares and ensure that they remain squared (as nothing about your current layout demands that your views should be squares).

If you want your 9 squares to remain in the center of the superview, I recommend adding them to an invisible intermediate view and center that within the superview.